How to import Static Analysis results into a Frequency Analysis study in SolidWorks?
I am looking for a way in SolidWorks, to import my static analysis results into a frequency analysis study, essentially creating a pre-stressed frequency analysis. However, I can't seem to find the correct method or option to do this. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

So what export options exist? What import options exist? no overlap?

@SolarMike The deformed model from the static analysis could be exported. However, when I try to use it for the frequency analysis, there is an error with the meshing. Other than that I can't seem to figure out any other options which could be used in my scenario.
